# Combo/select box display issue on WebBrowser control with IE11

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

When we update IE to version 11 on Windows 7 machine, found an issue in WPF which is to load a webpage with combo box inside. The issue is that the width of dropdown area is shorter than the combo box width. But the same page can display correctly with the whole width when open it  in IE11, IE8, and the same WPF
Is there a way to fix it to make it display with the whole width?

Html body:
Body:

```
<select style="width:200px">
  <option value="volvo">VolvoAutomation</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want to upload a image to show this question but my account can't upload images.